# How to fix SQLSyntaxErrorException?

Tags: java

I am Creating a Banking Management System and facing error in Deposit Class

> SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

The Code is:

```
try {
 String a = t1.getText();
 String b = t2.getText();

 if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
  if (t1.getText().equals("")) {

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter the Amount to you want to Deposit");

  } else {

   conn c1 = new conn();

   ResultSet rs = c1.s.executeQuery(" select * from bank where pin = '" + b + "' ");

   double balance = 0;
   if (rs.next()) {
    String pin = rs.getString("pin");

    balance = rs.getDouble("balance");

    double d = Double.parseDouble(a);

    balance += d;

    String q1 = "insert into bank values('" + pin + "','" + d + "',null,'" + balance + "')";

    c1.s.executeUpdate(q1);
   }
```

I have tried to resolve this problem but I am unable. The problem is that balance is not being inserted into bank table & this error is being faced by me, Please if anybody can help...

Comment: Debug your code and validate the value of q1. if you don't find any issue then try to execute the formatted query against database.

Comment: Do not use concatenation to provide variables for a query. It's prone to SQL injections. Look at `PreparedStatement` and use its `set` methods instead. As to your question - you should check what the values of the variables are at the time you execute the query. There's probably a corrupted one.

Comment: I doubt your `balance` column will be a `VARCHAR` or any text value. So I would start by check the data type and update the insert query. If the exception occurs during the `c1.s.executeUpdate(q1);` Also, you should know that you can't reuse a `Statement` without losing the resultset, so your `c1.s` will give you some problem at one point. Just Declare a `Statement` properly, and close everything, with exception management !

Comment: @AxelH balance have int datatype i have checked many more times, still the table is empty

Comment: I am using Oracle database

Comment: You are inserting `'123.456'` in a `int` value. That would be your problem.
It is easy to debug, print `q1` and execute the query, you will see that this is not a java problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use insert statement like below in your oracle database table, also make sure bank table has only 4 columns

```
String sql = "insert into bank values(?,?,?,?) ";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, pin);
pst.setString(2, d);
pst.setString(3, null);
pst.setString(4, balance);
```

Comment: Ah, some database manage the `null` in the setter. It is not true for every JDBC driver implementation (MySQL, Sybase are two that come to mind). Thanks for the input @PavelSmirnov